# Why is my PHP upload script not working when I export it in filezilla (other machines/server)?

Tags: php

//This is a sample file upload. it works fine in my localhost but it didn't work in intranet..
//This is my codes

```
<?php require_once "../session.php" ?>
<?php
$host='localhost'; // My hostname
$username='root'; // Mysql username
$password='*******'; // Mysql password
$db_name='jobs'; // DB name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$TARGET_PATH = "uploads/";
// Get our POSTed variables
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['uploadedfile'];
// Sanitize our inputs
$uploadedfile['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($uploadedfile['name']);

// Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e.  images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH .= $uploadedfile['name'];

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{
    $sql = "update personal set resume='" . $uploadedfile['name'] . "' where username='".$_SESSION['name']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
    header("Location: ../scripts/view.php");
    exit;
}
else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

?>
```

This only works in my pc (localhost using wamp). :((

Comment: Have you ever heard of "[debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)"?

Comment: PS: so your users cannot upload files with the same name?

Comment: PPS: google about "sql injections" as well

Comment: PPPS: there will be at least one mention about moving to PDO/mysqli after my comments

Comment: yup.. but i cannot debug it because im only using sftp to transfer data to other machines. and viewing it via http:://intranet

Comment: so what prevents you from editing the file through sftp?

Comment: PPPPS: assuming the upload succeeded... there's an `['error']` parameter in every $_FILES entry for a reason...\

Comment: is the upload folder writable?
check the permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure have appropriate permissions on `uploads/` folder. Use Filezilla to configure that.

Comment: thank you MaX... i already checked the permission to 777.. and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked my server its working fine i think permission issue on upload directory or may be possible path is wrong of upload directory.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

//your php code

```
<?php require_once "../session.php" ?>
<?php
$host='localhost'; // My hostname
$username='root'; // Mysql username
$password=''; // Mysql password
$db_name='blog'; // DB name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name);

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$TARGET_PATH = "uploads/";
// Get our POSTed variables
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['uploadedfile'];
// Sanitize our inputs
$uploadedfile['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($uploadedfile['name']);

// Build our target path full string.  This is where the file will be moved do
// i.e.  images/picture.jpg
$TARGET_PATH .= $uploadedfile['name'];

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))
{
    echo $sql = "update personal set resume='" . $uploadedfile['name'] . "' where username='".$_SESSION['name']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
    header("Location: ../scripts/view.php");
    exit;
}
else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }

?>
```